# Remember and show previously active nav-tab after hover mouseout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have few sub-tabs(nav-pills) under every main tab(nav-tabs). And i want to show them on hover over main tab while going back to the active main-tab after hover.

I have written jquery for hover but not sure how to go back to the previous active tab.Problem is that on mouse hover , the last hovered tab stays active.
My code is given below where

```
  $('.nav-tabs > li > a').hover(function () {
        //$($(this).attr('href')).show();
        $(this).tab('show');
    }, function () {
       // debugger;
        //if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {           //if ($(this).parent('li').hasClass('active')) {
        //    $($(this).attr('href')).show();
        //}
        //else {
        //    $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
        //}
    });
```

Comment: No need to use jquery here. You can (and should always) use css with pseudo element :hover. Modify there what you want to show.

Comment: Can you give an example on how to use pseudo element ?

Comment: Can you give the structure of your navigation and what you want to show/hide there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a class to recall your previous state when you are done hovering.

```
$('.nav-tabs > li > a').hover(function () {
    $('.nav-tabs > li.active').addClass('lastActive');
    $(this).tab('show');
}, function () {
    $('.nav-tabs > li.lastActive').removeClass('lastActive').children('a').tab('show');
});
```

Also you will need to add a click event that removes your lastActive class.

```
$('.nav-tabs > li > a').click(function () {
    $('.nav-tabs > li.lastActive').removeClass('lastActive');
    $(this).tab('show');
});
```

Something like this :)

Comment: $(this).tab('hide'); throws error -  Uncaught TypeError: e[b] is not a function

Comment: Sorry I was using my brain as the compiler is this better?

Comment: Hi @fjoe, removing tab('hide') did the trick . But now i cannot click on other tabs.

Comment: Had to think about it a bit but what is happening is your hover out event is forcing it back to the old state regardless of the click. So I added some code that should make the click event remove the state. Let me know if that fixes it?

Comment: Works now :). THanks a lot :)